# AddToRole() method doesn't result in db entry in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roles, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity in my ASP.NET MVC app. My problem occures while adding user to role. There isn't any exception, but as a result of um.AddToRole() no db entry is added to AspNetUserRoles table. My action method looks like that:

```
    public ActionResult GrantAdmin(string id)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = um.FindById(id);
        if (!rm.RoleExists("admin")) 
        {
            rm.Create(new IdentityRole("admin"));
        }
        um.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
        return View((object)user.UserName);
    }
```

um is an object of UserManager class:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

What can be a reason of that kind of application behavior? Any idea?

===EDIT===
It is my DbContext:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
```

And Default Connection in Web.config:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-RecommendationPlatform-20140404055015.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-RecommendationPlatform-20140404055015;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: This is going to sound like an odd question - though have you refreshed your SQL Management Studio list of databases since running this? There is a chance that it was looking at a different DB to the one you intended, and if it wasn't there it created it and added the user/role in that one. I only mention this because it happened to me too.

Comment: Yes, I was taking into account that possibility. But I can't see it there at all. No entries without exception suggests entries are being made in other place... But I've got no idea why it behaves like that and how can I indicate correct db explicitly @Darren. How did you solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're creating your DbContext? this is where you would explicity set the name of the connection string you want to use.

Comment: @Darren it is shown in the second part od my code. When I'm creating UserManager object (um) - the parameter od UserStore is new ApplicationDbContext().

Comment: It is true that I use in the same controller two other contexts included private ApplicationDbContext userDb = new ApplicationDbContext(); - because I have to get an access to the full list of users and I can't do that via UserManager.

Comment: No, I mean your actual context - the constructor of `ApplicationDbContext` - does it have a `: base("andAString")` - the string passed in is your connection name

Comment: It has DefaultConnection parameter. I've edited question to show it.

Comment: AddToRole returns a result IIRC. Can you check the result object maybe the answer is there.

Comment: Yees - there is an error message "User name name@gmail.com is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."

Comment: I guess that answers the question then. Shall I post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with ASP.NET Identity it is important to remember that many operations return a result object where eventual errors are stored. There are no exceptions. Therefore one should check the result object for success after every operation. This is true not only for roles but for most methods that save data to the database. Even if it works you should still test for success and eventually throw an exception if the result is not success.

As per the comments in your case the problem was invalid username.

Comment: In addition the errors are returned as strings. If you agree that they should be enums so that it is easier to know all possible errors and easier to handle them please upvote the issue I have posted on codeplex - https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2222