# UserManager.AddToRole failing silently for facebook logins

Tags: c#, facebook, azure, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net identity 2 & MVC 5 on azure websites. I created a few roles and have no problem assigning users (registered to the site as a local account) to the newly created roles .

The weird part comes only when i create an account using social log in (Facebook in this case).

I checked the tables [aspnetusers] & [aspnetuserlogins], everything looks ok...

Until i try assigning social accounts with roles. There was no exception and in my logger everything looks fine. What am i doing wrong?

```
var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var user = um.FindByEmail(email);
um.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
```

Just to be a little naggy: the role exists and i have no trouble assigning it to local accounts

Comment: The social login accounts have a valid/registered email ? (I guess they do or addtorole would throw a nullref exception.. :p )

Comment: yes they do, the only thing different in aspnetusers table, is that they don't have a password hash (which is normal?)

Comment: Yes that is normal (no pw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through stackoverflow, i finally stumble upon this comment [AddToRole() method doesn't result in db entry in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352361/addtorole-method-doesnt-result-in-db-entry-in-asp-net-identity#comment37653059_24352361)

after which, i've changed the line

```
um.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
```

to

```
var result = um.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
//log result.Errors
```

### Error message from `.AddToRole()`

**User name Lee Gary is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.**

After looking at the accounts creating locally, then i realised that all those accounts had their email as userid

### AccountController - Register

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() 
            { 
                // this line assigned email as username
                UserName = model.Email, 
                Email = model.Email
            };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

however, for god knows why, the MVC developers decided to let social log in users to enter their own usernames with no validation

### AccountController - ExternalLoginConfirmation

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser() 
            { 
                UserName = model.Name, //<--- model.Name = user input    
                Email = model.Email , 
                BirthDate = model.BirthDate
            };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);                        
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Finally to make sure that the username is A-OK, i've made a small change in `Register()`

From:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() 
{ 
    UserName = model.Name,    
    Email = model.Email ,
    BirthDate = model.BirthDate
};
```

To:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() 
{ 
    Name = model.Name,
    UserName = model.Email, 
    Email = model.Email ,
    BirthDate = model.BirthDate
};
```